# Magento: use subdomains as a CDN for media folder

Tags: magento, subdomain, cdn

We are planning to use subdomains ie.cdn1.example.com, cdn2.example.com to deliver product images.

How to configure Magento for this?

How to handle Magento cache folder which save auto-generated thumbnails as per template?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an origin pull CDN like AWS Cloudfront, you just fill in the information telling their system your web server name, they provide you with a server name (randomchars.cloudfront.net) on their end and then you use a CNAME record in your DNS to point their server name at your subdomain name like media.example.com.

Then your base media URL becomes http://media.example.com/media/ and everything's pretty much automatic from there.

Using origin pull gets rid of having to maintain a separate system to host your images and try to get Magento to upload to it, or figure out how to replicate Magento's media folder to it.

Comment: Thanks Fiasco, 
I find your answer very helpful, but the scenario here is we are not going to use origin pull CDN. 
We simply want to use a sub-domain to distribute media folder Images if possible.
Is there any way to shift media folder directly sub-domain?